# Rescue given anonymous module instead of exception class

Tags: ruby, exception

We can put a class or module after a `rescue` statement, but in the code below, I see a method following `rescue`, which does not fit into this pattern. How is it working and how is it producing the output it has been designed to show?

```
def errors_with_message(pattern)
  # Generate an anonymous "matcher module" with a custom threequals
  m = Module.new
  (class << m; self; end).instance_eval do
    define_method(:===) do |e|
      pattern === e.message
    end
  end
  m
end
puts "About to raise"
begin
  raise "Timeout while reading from socket"
rescue errors_with_message(/socket/)
  puts "Ignoring socket error"
end
puts "Continuing..."
```

Output

```
About to raise
Ignoring socket error
Continuing...
```

Comment: Pro-tip: if you format the code properly, it becomes much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Yes you said me the same previously also,and I kept in my mind as I did with my professors. Here I tried to keep the same,but failed. Sorry for that,forgive me as well. :(

Comment: No worries, keep trying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rescue requires a class or a module, true. So, that method creates an anonymous module with special behaviour. You see, when `rescue` searches for a handler, it applies `===` operator to exception classes/modules you provided, passing as an argument the actual exception.

```
begin
  # do something
rescue MyCustomError
  # process your error
rescue StandardError
  # process standard error
end
```

So, if `StandardError` (or one of its descendants) was raised, the first handler will be skipped and second handler will be matched.

Now, the module from `errors_with_message` is special. It redefines threequals operator to match on exception message. So, if an error was raised and its message contains word "socket", this handler will match. Cool trick, huh?

Comment: I think I need more explanation being a stupid boy.. :(. I just first wanted to know how Ruby allows to pass that method, as it is instructed to ruby - `not to pass anything except class or module`. Please help me here to digest first.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan: everything in ruby is an expression. Expressions are evaluated to produce their values. Value of expression `Array` is an `Array` class itself (as one would expect). Value of `errors_with_message` is a dynamically created module. Therefore, the requirement not to pass anything except class or module is met.

Comment: OMG! what a valuable statement you have given you might don't know, it reduced my next all confusions. That's why I need you. Please share your `email ID`. :)

Comment: Could you please also break this construct - `(class << m; self; end).instance_eval do
    define_method(:===) do |e|
      pattern === e.message
    end
  end` I have also folded with this construct,couldn't return out from there.

Comment: Instead of explaining this concrete construct, I will recommend you this book: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby). After you read (and understand) it, you will be able to produce MP magic like this by yourself :)

Comment: Downloaded also, :) something special for array,hash and Strings, any reference do you have?